# downvotes on a post made 4 years ago

Tags: discussion

I got a -2 down vote today for a post made 4 years ago, is this feasible? The question was closed as resolved.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11371731/chinese-characters-distorted-in-flash-on-linux

Comment: Such  happens all the time, so what?

Comment: The question has no answers. If you don't care about it, why not just delete it. Done!

Comment: Got it, just was a bit surprised because this is the first time I saw this thing.

Comment: @D_Bester may I delete this post too?

Comment: @fluter You can't delete this post now, since it got an upvoted answer. Don't worry about the downvotes on meta.

Comment: The time to wory a bit it when you get two downvotes, isued in the same, or consecutive, minutes on old, dead questions.  If you see the same happen on the next day, maybe flag it.

Comment: Ok, no worries this time.

Comment: wonder how would you feel about receiving _upvotes_ on a post made 4 years ago

Comment: same surprised too? it's more the age of the post gets me, not the downvotes, such old post usually would be "archived" in some way.

Comment: Downvotes on poorly formatted off topic questions are to be expected.

Comment: Yes, I know, the down vote did not come with a comment, so we never know his thoughts.

Comment: Note that "searched alot"/"thank you" text does not belong to questions... Essentially post is "there is an error. googled. thanks" - no MCVE, no details, most likely no longer possible to reproduce the same error, and more imprtantly no longer belong to SO (either SU or one of *nix.SE sites)... Not really surprising that someone randomly found the post or systematically checked particular tag for unanswered questions and downvoted the post.

Comment: Questions here are never *archived*. The entire purpose of this site is to build a knowledge base for future users; it would be extremely counter-productive to archive old questions and/or answers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You received a *single* downvote, which gave you a -2 reputation drop. Don't worry too much about it; people are free to vote as they like.

Getting worked up about a single downvote is a good way to drive yourself insane.